# Microsoft office Access database engine could not find the object

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I created a test MS Access DB to export a table to Excel and a text file.

This works for Excel:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "QryExportToExcel", _
acFormatXLS, XFile, False
```

For the text file, I created a specification and used this code

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "Mytable Import Specification", "mytable", "D:\myfolder\test1.txt", False
```

In the error message, I get **"test1#txt"**.

> The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object
>   "test1#txt". Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name
>   and the path name correctly.

[image: Error which i got]

I tried creating test1.txt in the same path. To my surprise, this deleted the file which is already present.

Software: MS ACCESS 2007

Comment: Sorry HansUp FileDir is "D:\myfolder\". For convinence i hardcoded path in this question.

Comment: Oh yes you are right. there is a problem with SpecificationName. If i remove that one i can export. But i need a delimeter for this export. how can i achieve without **SpecicationName** . Do you have any code?

Comment: Hey HansUp i got the error man. Its because i was using a Import Specification for Exporting a file. So i removed it and gave a Export Specification Name

Comment: You are exporting a delimited file, do you really need a specification at all? Are your delimiters non-standard?

Answer (score 1):

> The Microsoft Office Access databasse engine could not find the object "test1#txt". Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and path name correctly.

This is a generic (and rather useless) error message that Access outputs in case *anything* goes wrong. One example would be a misspelled field name in the import/export specification.

You can get the "real" error message by trying the import operation "manually" in the Access user interface (rather than through code).

Answer (score 1):

The question author reported the problem was *"because I was using an Import Specification for Exporting a file."*

They resolved the problem by using an Export Specification.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing DoCmd.TransferText, Access is expecting that the file Test1.txt exists in that location.  Try creating the file first, and then do a transfer of the text.

You can try this code before the export to create the file:

```
Public Sub CreateExportFile()
 Dim strFileName As String
 Dim SomeStringToOutput

 strFileName = "d:\myfolder\test1.txt"
 Open strFileName For Output As #1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar situation and found that a file *schema.ini* was in the destination folder.  This was created when an acExportMerge was performed previously and it caused this error.  Make sure that file has been deleted prior to executing a new TransferText.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while my ascii file contained a dot in its name (e.g.: something.something.log). I renamed the dot for an underscore (e.g. something_something.log) and it imported fine.